# Coupons - How to disable for some products

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, pricing

Our customers are able to use a Discount Coupon - we do not want to apply it to a particular - Category - our Clearance Category.

Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

This is quite easy to do. In your coupon rule's `Conditions` tab you will want to set up a rule like this:

[image]

This tells the rule NOT to apply if it ever finds 1 or more items in the cart where the category is your discount category. Make sure to fill in the proper category ID there.

Hope that helps! Cheers!